# Trying to recreate the Bootstrap 3, Angular JS and Typeahead demo example in Plunker

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to get a working Plunker with Bootstrap 3, Angular and Typeahead but I am finding some styles are missing and also my model doesn't appear to be binding properly. I have copied the code directly from the demo page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8BWdTjV3xllp6OWaMRFq

Am I using all the correct JS & CSS libraries here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your end goal is, but I created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8haTUW14z55CwMaZqyAF?p=preview) that might be what you're looking for. If so, I can add it as a solution and explain what I did.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get a tag editor function with dropdown and typeahead. As per this Git Project: https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput

Comment: I believe I got what you're looking for, check my answer below.

Comment: I was actually using a branch from here: https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/pull/146 - I guess this is not fully tested at this point and is the reason that the Angular Version does not appear on the Boostrap 3 versio of the Bootstraps Tags Input live Demos page here: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out what's wrong with your code by going to the [Github repo](https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput) you posted, used the source code of the [example page](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to create a fully-functional [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9bjdSb4itECyqg5AbWpf?p=preview) of the AngularJS example, and stripped it down until I came across code that did not match what you had. The following Plunker should be what you're looking for:

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNqaXOLmGzjJ4kmrUN0z?p=preview)

I made the following changes to your Plunker to get it working:

1. Your `bootstrap-tagsinput-angular-bs3.js` file did not match what I found in the above repository, so I replaced it with the repository's code. It seems that you were trying to use something called 'Hogan' which was causing issues. If that's important, leave a comment about what it is and why you need it and I'll look into it.
2. I removed the `typeahead.js` and `hogan.js` dependencies. The first is not needed because the `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` already uses it, and the second because, again, I'm not sure what this does.
3. For some reason, the `switch` statement inside your `$scope.getTagClass` function returns CSS classes that are invalid. I changed them to the following:

   ```
   case 'Europe'   : return 'label label-info';
   case 'America'  : return 'label label-danger label-important';
   case 'Australia': return 'label label-success';
   case 'Africa'   : return 'label label-success'; // Note that 'label-inverse' made the object invisible
   case 'Asia'     : return 'label label-warning';
   ```
4. You were trying to use a version of BootstrapJS that seems to not support this Typeahead component. I changed the `bootstrap.min.js` dependency from v3.1.1 to v2.3.2. Perhaps this is an unreported bug that you should look into.
5. You removed the `$http` service and `$scope.queryCities` function, but these were necessary to make the component work. You were trying to skip this by directly loading in `cities.json`, but this will only work for the initial populating of the Typeahead, and will cause the Typeahead predictive text feature to be non-functional. I added back in the `$http` service to your `CityTagsInputController` function, and the following function into the controller:

   ```
   $scope.queryCities = function(query) {
       return $http.get('cities.json');
   };
   ```
6. Finally, there are two things wrong with the attributes you pass into your `bootstrap-tagsinput` directive. As mentioned above, you cannot directly pass in `cities.json` into the `typeahead-source` attribute. I changed it to `quertyCities`. I also changed the `tagClass` attribute to `getTagClass` instead of `getTagClass(city)` -- this attribute only needs the name of the function, not any parameters (even if it did, you never defined `city` in the first place).

I made sure that each of the above changes was necessary by adding them back into the fully functional Plunker (above) one  at a time, and found that each one broke the code. So you will need to make all these changes to get your code to work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer, though I have thrown you a red herring in some ways, sorry. I actually was using the pull request from this page: https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/pull/146 - It appears that this hasn't yet been merged, and perhaps because it is not yet fully working. Your answer does work due to the downgrading from Bootstrap 3 to 2.3.2, I was trying to get the latest version working with V3. But I have just found that my version of Angular Bootstrap UI does not depend on Bootstrap 3 and actually I can downgrade to V 2.3.2 :) - Thanks Marking as answered.

Comment: Actually, if you want to be even more of a superhero, perhaps you can suggest a way that I can pop up the typeahead dropdown on focus of the field? So when a user tabs to the field they can then select with the down arrow immediately.. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest applying a class (e.g. `.bootstrap-tagsinput.focus`) to the `bootstrap-tagsinput` tag upon focus using `ng-focus`, then using `attrs.$observe()` to monitor when the class is added, and in the callback function, set `display: block` in the `<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">` tag that is auto-generated under the above directive. If you think that approach sounds good, post another question and I'll do my best to answer it!

Comment: I like the idea. I have now posed this as a new question, and would appreciate it if you could look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659072/how-can-i-show-the-bootstrap-tags-input-dropdown-automatically-upon-focus

Comment: I am so close to solving this! I can detect the focus like this:

`$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').focus(function () { alert("focus"); }); `
Now, how can I display the dropdown menu?

Comment: I am currently drafting an answer to your problem that I will post to the follow-up SO question. I will post it when I get the chance sometime after work!